# SQL: matching column's values as rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a noob at SQL things and I'm looking to do something here. I've search around and haven't found a way to do it, perhaps because I don't know how to explain it and therefore maybe I'm not searching correctly.

Here's the problem:
I have a Table with 3 columns that serves as an auxiliary set of properties for a different Table (but that's kinda irrelevant to the problem).

**What I have:**

```
--------------------------------------------
 listing_id  |  field_id  |  listing_value
--------------------------------------------
    1             Fruit        Apple
    1             Color        Red
    2             Fruit        Banana
    2             Color        Yellow
    3             Fruit        Grape
    3             Color        Purple
```

**What I want to get:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
 listing_id  |  listing_value_1  |  listing_value_2 
----------------------------------------------------
    1             Apple               Red
    2             Banana              Yellow
    3             Grape               Purple
```

Keep in mind this is all happening at the same table.
This is all for selecting values, so the query must start with `SELECT`

I've tried the `JOIN, GROUP and UNION` commands but I haven't gotten any successful results.

Also, I'm trying to get this to work via phpMyAdmin which lacks a few commands (for example I can't use `INTERSECT`, I can use `Select * FROM x` but can't seem to use`SELECT x.*`)

thanks in advance :)

Comment: There seems to be some major fail in that table. Perhaps try to re-design your table(s) ?

Comment: Please tag with the database engine you're using.

Comment: it's part of an existing (3rd party) system which would be a real pain to re-arrange. it's part of a WordPress plugin

sorry, using mySQL. is that enough info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.listing_id , t1.listing_value as listing_value1 , t2.listing_value as listing_value2
  FROM table t1, table t2 where t1.listing_id = t2.listing_id AND t1.field_id = "Fruit" AND t2.field_id = "Color"
```

Comment: didn't work for me, as I can't use t1.listing_id, I get an SQL syntax error. again, this is all from within phpMyAdmin (a mySQL table)

Comment: try code again, i was little mistake in typing it here, replace _table_ with your table name

Comment: works now, except I can't seem to use WHERE (same as the one below) without firing a syntax error. any ideas?

Comment: Look to [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), [AND/OR](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregate function and a `CASE`:

```
select listing_id, 
  max(case when field_id = 'Fruit' then listing_value end) listing_value_1,
  max(case when field_id = 'Color' then listing_value end) listing_value_2
from yourtable
group by listing_id
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83ce7/1)

Comment: that seems to work well, except I can't seem to use WHERE correctly now. always getting a bad syntax error
ie. imagine field_id can be Fruit, Color, Flavor and Origin, and I still only want Fruit and Color
any ideas?

Comment: @OscarSanz you place the `WHERE` before the `GROUP BY` clause, I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.